# How many integer partitions of a googol (10^100) into at most 60 parts

Tags: co.combinatorics

[**Ed.** Prof. Zeilberger has [explained](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/1091/3/how-many-integer-partitions-of-a-googol-10100-into-at-most-60-parts/#Item_27) why he was asking this question.  In joint work with Sills he had developed one approach to this problem, and he asked this question to see how this method compared to the current state of the art.  Thus in order to be most useful, answers should explain a technique for computing the number of partitions of a given number and explain how quickly that technique works on large numbers.]

I am offering $100 (one hundred US dollars) for the EXACT  number of integer-partitions of
10^100 (googol) into at most 60 parts.  The answer has to come by 23:59:59 Sat. July 30, 2011,
by Email to zeilberg at math dot rutgers dot edu . The first correct answer would  get the prize. Please have

Subject: MathIsFun; Computational Challenge for p_60(10^100) ;

Of course, the answer should also be posted on mathoverflow, this way people would know that
it has been answered.

P.S. A quick reminder, the number in question is the coefficient of q^(10^100) in
the Maclaurin expansion of
1/((1-q)(1-q^2)(1-q^3) .....(1-q^60))

Comment: This qualifies as "Math Is Fun", but I'm wondering if MathOverflow is really the right place. Doron, I assume that you know the answer, since otherwise how will you check that someone's answer is correct. MathOverflow is designed for people to ask questions to which they do *not* know the answer, in order to enlist the aid of the MO community. And posting an answer on MO is, to my mind, not a very useful thing. What might be useful would be to post an explanation of how one does the calculation. Anyway, I'm not voting to close, but I question the posting of "challenges" of this sort on MO.

Comment: First of all, welcome to MO. Second of all, I am voting to close your question (interesting as it may be)--because apparently you already know the answer. 

Comment: I'm not voting to close, even though I'm somewhat tempted to. I hope that whoever answers the challenge also posts a complete explanation of the method used (otherwise it's kind of useless). If nobody comes up with the answer by the deadline, then I'd hope Doron posts the answer himself, along with the explanation of the method. Finally, MO doesn't deal in US dollars: it deals in MO reputation points (see FAQ). There's a system of "bounties" by which a user can offer some of his MO reputation points for an answer to a particular question (of course, Doron would first have earn those points...)

Comment: Actually, I'm voting against closing.

Comment: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1091/how-many-integer-partitions-of-a-googol-10100-into-at-most-60-parts/

Comment: Actually, I'm voting against reopening.

Comment: I am curious to know the answer (well, not the exact number but how to get to it, and what is the point). Since the question is self-terminating in a weak or so I propose (thus cancelling Harald's vote) to reopen it until August 2. and then reconsider. I dont know if Doron knows the answer but if he does I hope this knowledge be shared (e.g. in an August 1 edit of the question). 

Comment: But why do people think that Doron knows the answer? Maybe, there is some quick way to check that the answer is right, but there is no known quick way to get the answer? 

Comment: @Fedor: If there's a quick way to check an answer (similar to, say factoring $n=pq$), then that information should be included as part of the question. My guess here is that it is not the case.

Comment: I'm voting to keep this question closed, because in any case, I do not think it is appropriate to offer cash prizes on MO. It would certainly be possible to rephrase this as an MO question, but not the way it currently reads.

Comment: I would try a wild guess for this challenge. log(X)/log(10) = 5737.9378 and the actual number is at: http://paste.ubuntu.com/651168/ 

Comment: Since it took me a while to figure this out, let me record it: all 'informal' votes seem to be cancelled, as André's initial vote against closing cancels Joe's.   

Comment: @Doron: with all due respect, a number of people are wondering why you are "asking" this question, i.e., posing this challenge. Such challenges are generally not considered an appropriate use of MO. And so, for an exception to be made, there should be good reason. Thanks. 

Comment:  @Doron, I am guessing that you are expecting that this is not possible in practice, so I would be interested to know what you are trying to demonstrate with this question. ps: if you don't further restrict the question, I can use a succinct form to give the answer (using an algorithm), so I guess you want an explicit answer in some normal form (say a string of decimal digits).

Comment: Dear Todd, I am also wondering but can't we wait for one week? I also agree with Joe that it is unlikely that we have here an example of a question which is hard to solve, has a quick way to check the answer, and easy to solve if you know some secret (like the factoring n=pq example). Not just because it is not mentioned in the original post but because if this is a new one-way function of this kind this would be spectacular beyond belief. 

Comment: Dear Gil, if a new one-way function application were the point of this, then what would be the harm of saying so now? It would add immensely to the interest of the problem, I'm sure, in the eyes of many. This is MO: let's be upfront and transparent. 

Comment: I think that Scott Aaronson may be convinced to give 100,000 dollars to DZ if indeed a new one way function was discovered here. (Which will leave Doron 99,900.) 

Comment: @Doron, please try http://math.stackexchange.com ;-) lol

Comment: I didn't finish the calculation, but my approach was to use partial fractions. I think a computer algebra system shouldn't have too much trouble computing the coefficient of $(q-\zeta_i^j)^{-k}$.

Comment: Dear Doron: In case you didn't follow the discussion on meta, I closed the question for the sole purpose of preventing spurious answers from appearing. Your question will remain on MO forever with the same visibility as any other question.

Comment: Doron, now that the problem was solved and the solution was confirmed, what was your point/motivation to start with? 

Comment: Gil 16:08: sorry, no dice. :-)

Comment: In sage p_60(10^100) was computed in 24 minutes : Time: CPU 1245.17 s, Wall: 1392.92 s

Comment: @Doron what is the period of the sequence mod p? Would it be possible your approach to give faster pseudo primality test?

Comment: This might be relevant for faster approach: A GENERAL METHOD FOR DETERMINING A CLOSED FORMULA FOR THE NUMBER OF PARTITIONS OF THE INTEGER n INTO m POSITIVE INTEGERS FOR SMALL VALUES OF m: http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/21-4/colman.pdf

Comment: Ooops, I did not mean to nominate for reopening. How do I undo?


Comment: @Andrej: wait until it reopens (now) then vote to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you do p_60(10^1000)? p_60(10^10000)? – Doron Zeilberger

8.6656581294960581213175060679076908106704497466613.. * 10^5737    Dollar 100
8.6656581294960581213175060679076908106704497466613.. * 10^58837   Dollar 1000
8.6656581294960581213175060679076908106704497466613.. * 10^589837  Dollar 10000

Comment: The further values are also correct, but it is not clear whether Peter had all the digits, or did it with floating point.
Joro did a great job, but still it took his computer two hours.
Shalosh can do it in two seconds once it found the quasi-polynomial
expression for p_60(n), and it found it in 400 seconds. So Shalosh
does first symbol-crunching then number-crunching. 

-Doron Z.


Comment: I failed to compute p_60(10^1000) in 12 hours.

Comment: Doron, after the symbol cranching stage once the quasi-polynomial expression was found, how quickly can shalosh compute p_60(10,000)

Comment: Shalom Gil,
  Good question. I bet you meant p_60(10^(10000)) NOT p_60(10000).
Using the Maple package PARTITIONS, soon to be posted in a joint work
with Andrew Sills, typing
 restart: read PARTITIONS: t0:=time():qmn(60,10^10000): time()-t0;

gave  3.121 seconds.

 If you want to actually see the 589838-digit integer, ending in

 71918678375357

it took 3.932 seconds.
          -Doron Z.

Comment: A link to the Sills-Zeilberger paper, which appeared recently on the arXiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4391

Answer (score 24):

Assuming the generating function is $\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{60}{(1-x^k)}}$ less than two hours of gp/pari computations gave the 5738 digit answer:

```
  p_60(10^100) =86656581294960581213175060679076908106704497466613021789269100257198717639235565191312316339492985931775559063255086528837813739104710297888706131590925777147446992989596305426558684312353832935177854304281051434707642789976633357008073006172513802039605620390971530655957695816047373679324636257282106902902642334621092094495020475520840128975825078563529533721223665030014973823745969613836273106408827327620882478583495948350012091274039702064403585282561588485459886814177864772537183125213711100412687405422437352195598054377411587222269453652608772595749758879318654363237967684143231492819869859849144643303192846597868095662984235221075244178993104547452731511881759746102529420779361469502083053597121420547771297370551721671548302500091286893415042409909386976998366647667730271589358498087377526580681061646805629741775292578165923941705511503682125111965696369869537104454897622661946756673714986529163822467578554047245492495510507170090948586721472176087890067187205068847873944550040070916438551321351396516213312259752977287529254685370643911843047105714953040605284080636692506692852386290861343553224074351341717615684759689286925891931418713944578600404523388228164949290655986905260347937245272959342219230306425929769819674715342009178833416712244795668148759773978550600441248548844394745844052334403899748841438534047816714279171794504022130682781281338860748886310942696518241739354639469191565831755281487651975490310571755217751161614063490987562368769323044232577035098658230233013237255973046519611557796486164097780600572765717192049207954645676522794492200060665810654697408765940922890681071570384648258924284066002369593013417037460844987760581310856784498330666017867379926932694902997867177534401534253516077108815999378705993544948398373531228390862058340486152600008916251487948597447302087222445574918132585218917475956102854139673493135870736987796597089097002154332556076681792911960393717282441400003891789494260210518618598398188973314601719313940864500046963578450894149843678435403526369044654570577736547494560409713817349951247573596666312987608479125353084495156167369686044416320507047788675965257815987123582326728091964213648779393844782376881912696986212395145284269498793326663270251644721155827704955889017550948057150607407340515621974551535912800395378923117298039858992279692113890732218616186715963928401879310471182014398714662911530318387903719384123094503523206696497344490492638446160520515345185475243301577733068288864511852204443105974689867573265717663992266843175679920468623776646192750361660066693548858340497070820836336832199589479748493873317664342726797884461623034017101485138334977039474244928106432671579231185307999275082811493423960476932458859071426598186180193873112974561741389243099450104083630784275091797080843197458051593402628198584022892884659157159673262136007475012211642068258586790111983004487115216316587714983184061600620955510042347951208525065607903584615122754411093720333997372104303686158116390169328647564729654602496822021852772627790051147655497081758653708323731069376329211820329894720964292204308512951279394392815381531228647996748926021980587998964261559656789935515903400714034275245390786720943646069317133415476977019995552930699089095507184260562010127210662513680400195596743618969063736866638772821443713466075147525295691845979077397586672472600601543352722962465248875034380223555307587552833073676295297462269930775994370058825449794499092333098572763536845613567842007659729575950101377792470604573148496958694358500851681021020417594633650488157803555292646903284496164708723320577897705653022386786879215494849887211690867003601123525598841552234310761205697727878524537734677467073785042424099919327513045482888697810675989587429823477178875557088606857135477182172185015519236919521892931144178066734476513787554644960056748117699500499619773294247239228662598512935502836101729578744392303964471746249068504824095375264500084786240673237030325688054879312901256140411126019876717562604656695370754259610380124733596290494150939078833029847277734279848103655035634005537012357440970178134041530010383962758911236744087548957247418495385838344050488193120198883656103937944047482394289200718538660178091001587195284171526798215466184392607070866663303013384407124487552431242699246058135314350852485524272063343281779127361940425132806724989541986633960769535303122467306918016412450564031174033910533590190086814981425286256620935490998866145273905397216624258819860307507105774061029397025943293906050905675435357400232306328073568576501790379120117667898974043944187447981387549878960713202932947775104921101559396576930010856892403392376903132049196798179726054506703688678257002906484375930174337243347713509605577865904845933780545352176065540746989843910448263598464743883743439272998551440273145595918471962680847257889187644711316597456792335590005247303224359521888113127081850435754309177603997607819802516595862380433682384768629515466542262017881243664146776012340346962436435902670624415630984638855161435213820664151078798248565386059057915029104772346437888653030556324179188240674032973292350468414546941023474634728292600948182617121556982271419859775728848796694902653386079448715972566638129584559954562361057167423402068307675741886341592218981106331969215861131581250781124740005504878113203950194519164264383901294959862497186017815081914576467308984426624348931287895061495731260738434212734724426778408532295618503758135224149897249857036284783900183976954684955435242114417114172532305756633722611320470393047211480479720666959127636504139868217145958399715530772463153560598077341901760982207337893156549165428179577945947050066009093850246495381004264287660200535241771035068278713633310388540
```

I am not sure this is correct at all, yet Doron seems happy.

**EDIT**: Here is how the number was computed. The generating function $\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{60}{(1-x^k)}}$ means the sequence satisfies linear recurrence with constant coefficients. These are known to be efficiently computable assuming arithmetic operations in the range of the result are tractable. A good computational resource for recurrences is the free book ["Matters Computational" was: "Algorithms for Programmers"](http://www.jjj.de/fxt/fxtpage.html#fxtbook) by Jörg Arndt. Basically the method is fast binary exponentiation of a matrix or in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/poly(x)$. The book has [code](http://www.jjj.de/pari/) parts of which I used. Got a linear recurrence of order 1830. My gp/pari code is [here](http://pastebin.com/rpCSgvZw). A curiosity of the challenge is the result is so small - I wouldn't even try $fibonacci(10^{100})$.

To my knowledge the monetary bounty was donated to Wikipedia by Doron Zeilberger per agreement with the recipient.

**EDIT2** A closed form possibly leading to faster approach (avoiding computing the recurrence) appears in the [paper](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/21-4/colman.pdf)
A GENERAL METHOD FOR DETERMINING A CLOSED FORMULA FOR THE NUMBER OF PARTITIONS OF THE INTEGER $n$ INTO $m$ POSITIVE INTEGERS FOR SMALL VALUES OF $m$, W. J. A. COLMAN

Comment: The answer is correct, Bravo! I am not sure who joro is, but Gerogi Guniski sent me Email a few minutes ago, with the correct answer, and
whether he is joro or not, Georgi won the prize!
Georgy, Can you do p_60(10^1000)? p_60(10^10000)?


Comment: Prof. Zeilberger, I invite you to follow the link to the meta discussion and consider the points there.  I especially invite you to consider the rewrites suggested for your question, or even better, to rewrite it yourself according to MathOverflow guidelines.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.24

Comment: @Doron, please try math.stackexchange.com ;-)

Comment: @Doron p_60(10^10000) appears tractable, though probably not with gp/pari but with something using FFT multiplication. It is probably tractable for my personal hardware too.

Comment: I was hoping to see some explanation since I thought this kind of computation is not tractable. This answer is right but doesn't offer any insight :(.

Comment: @Chao the question is interested in a number, not how to compute it. You can ask another question, but have in mind the OQ is closed :-)

Comment: Since joro is not sure at all if the answer is correct, and since it is still a mystery if Doron knew the answer to start with, and since the correctness of the answer may be irrelevant to Doron's initial point/motivation (which are also mysterious). It would be nice if the answer can be independently confirmed.

Comment: Dear Joro, since I am still curious about the question and the answer can you add a little more about the algorithm, how the computer reached the answer and which package (if at all) was used?

Comment: @Gil @Chao explained how the result was computed and gave full source code.

Comment: In sage p_60(10^100) got computed in 24 minutes : Time: CPU 1245.17 s, Wall: 1392.92 s